# How to solve Bad signature code 190 when try login in facebook

Tags: facebook, xamarin, facebook-graph-api, xamarin.forms

I´am following this tutorial [tutorial login facebook xamarin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGW9Q4atJN) to do login in facebook using xamarin, sometimes i get the following erro:

```
{
"error": {
  "message": "Bad signature",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 190,
  "fbtrace_id": "AO97gtDS9YV3BPFzKKM4vUG"
 }
}
```

I have the method, if i debug and get the variable requestUrl and put in browser i get the json erro above:

```
public async Task<FacebookProfile> GetFacebookProfileAsync(string accessToken)
    {

        var requestUrl = new Uri(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/me/?fields=id,name,picture.width(500).height(500),email,gender&access_token={0}", WebUtility.UrlEncode(accessToken)));

        var httpCliente = new HttpClient();

        var response = await httpCliente.GetStringAsync(requestUrl);//the exception happens here

        var facebookProfile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookProfile>(response);

        return facebookProfile;
    }
```

why this happen and How can i solve this problem?

Comment: "Access Token Expired" - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/error-handling/

Comment: Yeah I wish it was that. The moment I get the access code I make the request and get the same error.